# How to inspect and fix Bing's "Crawl errors"

Tags: bing, crawl-errors, bing-webmaster-tools

I signed up for Bing's Webmaster Tools and submitted my sitemap. The "search performance" blade shows this report with 12 crawl errors:

[image: crawl errors]

Nowhere on the site could I find information about those errors. My server did not throw errors in the last two days either. So I assume that these are purposeful errors, like 404 or 401.

How can I find details about these crawl errors that Bing found?

Answer (score 2):

[image]Uncheck the options aside from the errors, and then click the SEO Reports section to see the errors. They should be listed individually, and a lot of them, (missing alt tags, multiple h1, description missing) are pretty simple to fix just by updating the content. Other error messages will require editing the template or theme or whatever code base you are using.

EDIT: Errors are found under the SEO Reports section.

Comment: Are you sure ?  That shows me a blank page for my site and I do have crawl errors.

Comment: @Klesun I lost access to the console. Can you advise if this works for you?

Comment: Yes, it does, though the "Uncheck the options aside from the errors" does not seem to be required. I also have to wonder whether Crawl Errors = SEO Errors...